# Conversion wchar a string para pasarlo a unicode Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Hola estoy haciendo la siguiente conversion:

```
wchar_t buffer[5];
QString string = QString::fromWCharArray(buffer);
char *utf8encoded = string.toUtf8();
```

Pero parece darme el siguiente error:

> 'inicializando' : no se puede realizar la conversi¢n de 'QByteArray' a
>   'char *' No hay disponible ning£n operador de conversi¢n definido por
>   el usuario que pueda realizar esta conversi¢n, o bien no se puede
>   llamar al operador

Segui la documentacion pero sigo con el mismo error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en que el método [`toUtf8()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toUtf8) de la clase `QString` devuelve una variable de tipo `QByteArray`, mientras que tu estás intentando almacenar el resultado en una variable de tipo `char*`.

Por lo que deberías cambiar esto:

```
char *utf8encoded = string.toUtf8();
```

Por esto:

```
QByteArray utf8encoded = string.toUtf8();
```

Pero si necesitas trabajar con datos de tipo `char*`, en la clase `QByteArray` dispones de un método llamado [`data()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#data) que te devuelve un puntero a los datos. De esta forma podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
char *utf8encoded = string.toUtf8().data();
```

Saludos.